# Foreign key issue in UserProfile django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I want to retrieve User profile data of User who is logged in. e.g. Based on logged in user I want to retrieve the country of the user from userprofile. Seems straightforward but I am missing some fine print. Tried a lot but no success.

Need help. I tried and referred django document but I am a newbie

I am having following model.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    dob = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
```

Comment: If your user is supposed to have **one** `UserProfile` then you should have a `OneToOneField` not a `ForeignKey`. With these models, each `User` can have multiple profiles: `profiles = request.user.userprofile_set.all()` will give you all the profiles, if you want the first one's country: `profiles[0].country`.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: i am getting IndexError: list index out of range with profiles[0].country and profile.count() = 0

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200317/8138584

Comment: - changed to OneToOneField. Now how to get userprofile from logged in user i.e. request.user instance?

Comment: as the example in the link I posted shows, `user.userprofile` (lowercase of the class name) is the profile for the user. Or, set a `related_name` on your field, which will replace `userprofile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `request` comes to `view` functionality of `django` it has parameter called `request.user`.   this is an apporach you should use.

```
if(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()): 
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    user_country = user_profile.country
```

or if you use a `OneToOneField`

```
request.user.userprofile.country
```

***Suggestion:***
1. When using custom user model define custom manager also.
2. relation should be `OneToOneField` between User and UserProfile.

***Explaination of above code.***
I used `objects.get()`  But according to your model `objects.filter()` you should use because `ForeignKeyField` has many-to-one relationship.so same user **may** have many user profiles.

Comment: should be get(user=...) but that's an unnecessary detour, and not good practice, since you can just get `request.user.userprofile`

Comment: @dirkgroten '`request.user.userprofile` will use join query while get will use only select query  (single query)

Comment: first check if request.user is `None `or not.  @cyberspider789  .  otherwise post your code and error as well in question.

Comment: -@Naveen Jain -I have converted to OneToOneField and then run migrations and then tried your code but user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(usr=request.user) gives TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable
- request.user is not None when checked prior to running what you suggested.

Comment: @NaveenJain code readability is always more important than anything else. Don't optimise things that are futile, a join query is also just one query.

Comment: @cyberspider789 did you try `request.user.userprofile`? Also please update your question to show us your full error, the error you're mentioning cannot come from this particular line of code.

Comment: @dirkgroten  i have added that as well . thanks   Join just take more time thats why i wanted to give that answer but you are also correct that for new user readability issue comes.

Comment: seems like today my problem is solved. Please help..I am still stuck.

Comment: @cyberspider789 what is specific problem you getting . you should give specific code as well in question .  bdw i updated code as wll see which one is working for now at least

Comment: @NaveenJain it's not even true. `user.userprofile` just does the same query as `UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=<id>)`: SELECT * FROM user_userprofile WHERE user_userprofile.user_id = 160

Comment: here is the difference in get method i put a object but you have written user_id = ,id. .  evaluation of related model does take place here if i am correct. ?@dirkgroten

Comment: id is just user.id which is an object that's already in memory. Your query is actually doing exactly the same, the SQL for it is still `user_id = id`.

Comment: How to use related_name ? I am learning by looking at your kind of expert people.
- I have updated code for onetoone relationship. - I am using simpleJWT to authenticate user by obtaining token which is running fine. As soon as I get token, my user also logs in but story ends there, I can not determine any field from profile hence needs help

Comment: @cyberspider789 why did you add it if you don't know how to use it? You should always do things one step at a time. And you should learn to read the documentation. Remove it and you can do `user.userprofile`. Add it and you can do `user.profile`.

Comment: @dirkgroten i think than i have to read django doc again . now i got confuesed about this optimization thing.   but lets not deviate from topic .

Comment: @cyberspider789 please read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Comment: @cyberspider789 .you should mention the reference of problem as well. we here trying to help you out.

Comment: @dirkgroten i have one question i am posting that in 5 mins. is it possible to tag you in question so you can get notified that i have a question related to django

Comment: sorry Naveen sir, will keep in mind. Hope the context is clear now.

Comment: @cyberspider789 does request.user.id is giving the id ?

Comment: Just checked...yes it gives a reply as 1 i.e. 1st user i created.

Comment: ok then first try step by step apporach ..  `user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)`  and after that check if 'user_data' is giving any object or queryset??

Comment: @Naveenji.....trid this user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
and got this....users.models.UserProfile.DoesNotExist: UserProfile matching query does not exist.

Comment: it means in your UserProbile table in database user with id 1 does not exist . @cyberspider789 .   objects.get() gives DoesNotExist only if no row feteched

Comment: naveenji, let me purge all migrations and then try and then i will accept your answer. will take a few mins.

Comment: @cyberspider789 only accept when you understand what went wrong in your code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200325/discussion-on-answer-by-naveen-jain-foreign-key-issue-in-userprofile-django).